# simpler C# code to introduce 1 mSec delay?

Tags: c#

I am not using Thread so can't use thread.sleep() method.. Its part of my program where I need to introduce some delay .. Not precisely 1mSec but almost that ..

which is the standard method that is known to be so??

Comment: As you can see from the answers there are plenty of problems with 'introducing a delay'. It might help if you could indicate what it is for.

Comment: You'll need to P/Invoke timeBeginPeriod(1) to get the Thread.Sleep() accuracy down to a millisecond.  Use pinvoke.net for the declaration.

Comment: @Hans, thanks for the response, I just wanted to know the method, I have got to use it in many programs, well I will follow up your suggestion. :) if you could post it as an answer .. I would be able to accept it as an appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sleep 1msec. It will not be accurate at all. Read for instance [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/sleepstudy.aspx) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303667/how-accurate-is-thread-sleeptimespan)

Thread.sleep will always suspend the current thread. Keep in mind that it's not a good idea to use Sleep on a GUI thread (if your app is a winform app).

Answer (score 9):

You are always using a thread. Every application has at least one thread, so Thread.Sleep will work fine.

Comment: @Henk I might be taking some liberties on the "but almost" part of the question :)

Comment: One thing worth noting is that you could potentially 'sleep' for 20 ms at any time without even calling Sleep, due to a context switch by Windows' preemptive multitasking scheduler.  If there is an upper bound on the acceptable delay, there is already a bigger problem.

Answer (score 5):

> I am not using Thread so can't use thread.sleep() method

Not sure you you say that -- you can use `Thread.Sleep` anywhere you like.

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know, a 1msec sleep isn't guaranteed be exactly 1msec, in fact it's very improbable due to it being such a small time. The thread.sleep(x) states x as a minimum sleep time, if you wan't a much more exact sleep you might want to look into win32 multimedia timers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742877.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to provide an opportunity for thread switching, then use `Thread.Sleep(0)`.  (This is equivalent to `Thread.Yield()` in Java.)

Edit: actually seems like they've added `Thread.Yield()` in .NET 4.