# Alternative for Thread.Sleep() to temporarily suspend program

Tags: c#, wait, sleep

See the code at the bottom of this post. It's supposed to add "3" to the listbox, then "2" a second later, then "1" a second later and then run the main code of the program. However, once I execute the program it just stays blank 3 seconds long, after which all 3, 2, and 1 are shown, after which all the code directly starts. I want to visually see every number show up with a one second delay. How do I do this?

```
private void Main()
        {
            countdown();
            //Main Code
        }

private void countdown()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add("3");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            listBox1.Items.Add("2");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            listBox1.Items.Add("1");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Try to search, Thread.Sleep() blocks the UI thread, use a timer.

Comment: Putting the UI thread of a GUI program to sleep is a rather drastic mistake with potentially nasty consequences.  Not seeing the update is just a minor mishap, there's worse.  Users like responsive programs, no point in making it intentionally slow.  Use a Timer for animation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

async / await to the rescue:

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Add("3");
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    listBox1.Items.Add("2");
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    listBox1.Items.Add("1");
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**First**: Why isn't anything happening?

The reason is, that you are currently in the UI thread. By doing `Thread.Sleep` you suspend the very same thread you expect to draw the items you just added.

**Second**: How to work around this?

As @CodeCaster mentioned, you could use a `Timer` to do all this. You could also put your code in a `Thread` and call the `Add` method by using a `Dispatcher` or the `SynchronizationContext` class and it's `Send` method.

**Third**: A small hint on the `Sleep` method.

Usually it should do what you expect it to, but there is no guarantee for that. Calling `Sleep` means that your thread will be suspended for *roughly* the amount of time you want it to. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303708/937093)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Timer` having the interval set to `1000`. Start the timer when you want it to raise `Tick` event. Stop it to stop raising `Tick` event. Handle the `Tick` event and run the code in intervals.

But to have a countdown 3-2-1 function using async-await as it's suggested in the other answer is good idea:

```
private async void countdown()
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Add("3");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    listBox1.Items.Add("2");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    listBox1.Items.Add("1");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `listBox1.Refresh();` after every `Sleep()` call.

You are letting the thread sleep, but the UI does not get repainted automagically.