# Is it wise to use timer(s) with a windows service?

Tags: c#, service, timer

I have a console service I'm currently testing. I was planning on using a timer for it to last all day, with an interval check every 30 seconds, however, it looks like alot of people don't like using timer's with a service in that fashion. Is It wise to use a timer? or is their a better method to approach it?

Comment: what are their reasons not to like using them in that fashion? what's your reason to run it that way?

Comment: What are you going to check every 30 seconds?  That's often enough to interfere with power saving and cause noticeably reduced battery life.

Comment: You might want to think about what happens if the action takes longer than 30 seconds... do you start doing the same task multiple times concurrently? Or wait for the first one to finish?

Comment: Its ment to do the same task all day every day. it checks for incoming messages, and stores them to their appropriate destination.

Comment: @Alex: I would look to see if there's a way to have the incoming message trigger your code, instead of polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to have timers inside a service.

The question you should be asking yourself is whether you need your own service, or can just leverage a service that's already running timers (*Task Scheduler*).  Or perhaps you should instead be responding to a user action.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at task scheduler's before doing anything final, at the moment just testing that it works.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect they are trying to get you to do it using a thread based method [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032808/how-to-have-a-loop-in-a-windows-service-without-using-the-timer), which is arguably superior as the wait method is designed to awake correctly in response the the service interface.

If you need to launch very frequently the service approach is better than a scheduled task.

Comment: That seems inferior to the WaitableTimer... but I'm not sure if there's a .NET wrapper for `CreateWaitableTimer` and friends.

Comment: I did not say it was better, I said some argue that it is better -- some people like the OP referred to that are opposed to timers in services. Timers are more familiar, but the AutoResetClass avoids the use of an additional timer resource -- minor technical advantages, harder to understand

Comment: WaitableTimer is not the same as the .NET `Timer` class.  It's a waitable handle like the auto-reset event.  The code you linked is fine as long as it's desired to *sleep for a fixed interval without regard to task processing time* and not perform a task at a fixed frequency.