# Creating a Non-Reentrant "Non-Pausing" Timer using a volatile bool

Tags: c#, timer

I have seen plenty of examples ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055820/non-reentrant-timers) and elsewhere) of creating a non-reentrant timer by stopping the timer when the elapsed handler method is called and starting it again at the end of the elapsed handler method. This seems to be the recommended approach. The problem with this approach is that you will have a gap in time while the Elapsed Handler Method is running. You could end up with timing that is off by quite a lot within a short period of time.

So I was thinking about a better approach and I can up with the idea to use a bool to determine the state of the Timer, and whether the Elapsed Handler is currently running or not, it is is running then the call to the Elapsed Handler is returned immediately and the rest is not executed.

Below is the basic Idea

```
volatile bool _IsProcessingElapsedMethod = false;
private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_IsProcessingElapsedMethod)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Warning: Re-Entrance was attempted and Ignored.");
        return;
    }
    _IsProcessingElapsedMethod = true;

    //** DO Something here

    _IsProcessingElapsedMethod = false;
}
```

There has to be a reason I have never seen anyone do this. Am I missing some obvious Gotcha? It seems like a pretty easy solution.

Below is a compilable example.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace QuestionNon_ReEntrantTimer
{
    class Program
    {
        static private int Timer1_ElapsedCount = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NonReEntrantTimer timer1 = new NonReEntrantTimer(500);
            timer1.Elapsed += Timer1_Elapsed;
            timer1.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Any key to Exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            int delayTime;

            if(Timer1_ElapsedCount < 10)
            {
                delayTime = 300 * Timer1_ElapsedCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                Timer1_ElapsedCount++;
                delayTime = 400;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Timer1_Elapsed Call Count is {Timer1_ElapsedCount} Waiting for {delayTime} ms");
            Task.Delay(delayTime).Wait();

        }
    }


    public class NonReEntrantTimer : IDisposable
    {
        Timer _timer = new Timer();

        public event ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed;

        volatile bool _IsProcessingElapsedMethod = false;

        public NonReEntrantTimer(double interval)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(interval);
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        }

        public void Start() => _timer.Start();

        public void Stop() => _timer.Stop();

        public void Close() => _timer.Close();

        private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_IsProcessingElapsedMethod)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Warning: Re-Entrance was attempted and Ignored.");
                return;
            }
            _IsProcessingElapsedMethod = true;

            Elapsed?.Invoke(sender, e);

            _IsProcessingElapsedMethod = false;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this simple async pattern. It executes the given `Action` every `ts`, but starts countdown to the next execution *before* starting the current iteration. If the execution takes more time than `ts`, the next iteration is postponed till after the previous one finishes.

```
async Task ExecuteEvery(TimeSpan ts, Action a, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        var currentDelay = Task.Delay(ts, ct);
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await currentDelay; // waiting for the timeout
            currentDelay = Task.Delay(ts, ct); // timeout finished, starting next wait
            a(); // executing action in the meanwhile
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // if we are cancelled, nothing to do, just exit
    }
}
```

You can stop the iterations by cancelling the token. You can offload the action execution to the thread pool by starting the operation with `Task.Run`.

---

Update: if you want the timer to try catching up after the slow action, you can do it with some minor changes:

```
async Task ExecuteEvery(TimeSpan ts, Action a, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        for (var targetTime = DateTime.Now + ts; !ct.IsCancellationRequested; targetTime += ts)
        {
            var timeToWait = targetTime - DateTime.Now;
            if (timeToWait > TimeSpan.Zero)
                await Task.Delay(timeToWait, ct);
            a();
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // if we are cancelled, nothing to do, just exit
    }
}
```

Comment: It pauses it only if the execution takes too long, but it would still pause it and timing would then be off the original interval. Or am I missing something? I know there is not Hard Timing in C#, but I would like to get as close as possible. Also isn't Task.Delay rather inaccurate? I have heard it can be off as much as 50ms.

Edit: I guess I might not have been clear in my post about my desire to have no pausing at all.

Comment: @TheColonel26: No, on the contrary. The pause equals to the given timeout value unless the action takes longer than the timeout. E. g. if timeout time 10 s and action time 2 s, the next action will start in 8 s after the previous one. But if action time is 12 s (longer than the timeout), the next action will start immediately.

Comment: Yes, but, If say the first action takes 12 seconds, next action executes immediately and takes say 4 seconds. Then the next action executes after 6 more seconds. which is 22 seconds after start, and not 20 Seconds, now everything is off by 2 seconds, if you have another action take 13 seconds, then everything is off by 5 seconds. etc. my example code doesn't do that.

Comment: @TheColonel26: Okay, added another variant