# log4net is not working while windows service run automatically

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net

I have created a windows service program & install the service: following configuration used for log4net:

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="All" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\\Logs\\Menca.DataImportService\\%property{LogName}\\%property{LogName}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2000" />
  <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

When I start service manual it is logging properly for first time but it is not logging when it runs after defined interval. I have used timer in code to run process in every 24 hours. But it is not creating log on next period.

```
System.Threading.Timer _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(TimerTick),
                null,
                0,
                24 * 3600000
             );
```

Timer will be called in every 24 hours:

```
private void TimerTick(object sender)
    {
        try
        {
            // Thread.Sleep(15000);
            rCount = 0;
            iCount = 0;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

            _eventLog.WriteEntry(string.Concat("Scheduled Service Call Start Hour: ", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));

            Helper.StartDataDump();

            _eventLog.WriteEntry(string.Concat("Scheduled Service Call End Hour: ", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
            _eventLog.WriteEntry(string.Concat("Scheduled service call was processed successfully! : ", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errMsg = ex.InnerException == null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message;
            _eventLog.WriteEntry("Error occured in scheduled service call Exception: " + errMsg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your TimerTick method doesn't seem to use Log4net!

Comment: I have used it inside Helper.StartDataDump(); that i didn't included above, anyway finally I found the problem log4net were initialized only once when service started & then it will use same configuration all times it was writing log but on same configured path.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with log4net, since you're not even using it (`WriteEntry` is an `EventLog` method, not an `ILog` method). To use log4net, you need to confgure, get the logger from `LogManager`, then use the logging methods. Sample:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("root");
log.Info("Information message");
```

However, the issue you're having is with `Timer`. I would recommend accomplishing what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797382/724591) has, since it will start the next timeout *after* the current callback is finished.

```
private Timer _timer;
private ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("root"); // Get the log4net logger
private const int _timeoutInMilliseconds = 10000;    // 10 seconds

public void Start()
{
    _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timerTick),
            null,
            _timeoutInMilliseconds, // Timeout to wait until the callback is called
            Timeout.Infinite        // Makes sure it's only called once
         );
}
private void timerTick(object sender)
{
    _logger.Info("Sample");
    _timer.Change(_timeoutInMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite); // Wait 10 seconds again
}
```

Otherwise, you could fix your timer so it calls the callback after a certain timeout by doing:

```
_timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timerTick),
        null,
        0,                     // Set a time here for an initial timeout
        _timeoutInMilliseconds // It will call timerTick every 10 seconds
     );
```