# C# Schedule a window service

Tags: c#, service, timer

I have a window service and i'm using `System.Timers.Timer` to schedule my service

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer_= new System.Timers.Timer(intervalTime * 1000);
    timer_.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEvent);
    timer_.Enabled = true;
}


private void TimerEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSth();
}
```

I find that, the `Dosth()` function doesn't run exactly when i start the service, but after `intervalTimer` seconds.I want it to run exactly after i start the service, so i call the function `Dosth()` before statment `timer_.Enabled = true;`. But i got another problem that. the distance of the 1st and the 2nd process is not exactly equal `intervalTime`, but base on processing time of `DoSth()` function. How can i solve this?

Comment: How about you call `Dosth()` after `timer_.Enabled = true;`

Comment: To answer your first question just call `DoSth();` in the `OnStart` event before wiring up the timer. If you just want a program to run at set times then have you thought about moving to a console application and scheduling execution with windows task scheduler?

Comment: The trick to equal intervals is to get a [time stamp at the start of the callback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12797382/314291), and then to measure the time in the callback and subtract this from the next tick interval. Also, do one interval at a time (`Timeout.Infinite`) to prevent reentrancy issues.

Comment: @artm: It still not work :(

Comment: Take a look at Quartz.net, makes the above very easy. Also have a look at Topshelf too, it makes writing services much more simple.